# Android Custom Dialogue Box

Tags: android, android-layout, photoshop

Hi I want to make a custom dialogue box for my android application and want to populate it with buttons, check boxes and such kind of items. 
I have followed the tutorial from android developers website, but that is not what I want, actually I want to customise the background and size of the dialogue box. 
Please if any body could give me a head start, Plus I want to know when I design a background for that box, what dimensions and pixel numbers I use so that it may run the same in Galaxy Note, Galaxy S and tablets and other mobile phones running android. 
Here is the picture of customised dialogue box. Like that I want to work out something. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a good question. You must use a custom dialog with a transparent bg theme like these:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

where `custom_dialog` will be your XML for the dialog layout, and as far as dimensions go you should really test your app on a number of different screen resolution devices to ensure it displays as you want.

Comment: Thank you Marci, Let me work on that. I hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On occasion I have wanted to create a fully customized dialog such as the one you've shown.

When I had to do it, I fought for a while trying to make it a Dialog. In the end I found it was far easier to just wrap my dialog in its own activity, set it to theme transparent in the manifest, and make the layout xml file such that there was transparent space around the edges. That was the easiest way for me to get rid of all of the default dialog formatting (i.e. the frame that it comes in if you do it with the setContentView() route)

So while it is not technically a dialog any more, to the user it serves the same purpose.

Comment: for future projects what you needed to do was use the sample code I posted here :) good luck

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect, I could've swore that I tried something like that but ended up still having the default dialog background. the style must've been what I was missing.